Unity in Android - weird squares on sprites
today I finally released my game for Windows (without any problems), so I wanted to do the same for Android.
However when I switch to Android platform in Unity, some parts of my sprites looks weird (there are some random orange squares and on some places the textures just look bugged (https://prnt.sc/Pv5HqFZKxnjj) - I put circles around the weird spots, so you can see it. It's on the same type of sprites on same spots.
When I open the sprites normally in any editor, the squares are not here, it's just in Unity (it's same when I build and run the game on actually Android phone.
Has anyone encountered same problem?
Thanks for any help!
EDIT:
Here is link to screenshot of the sprite settings in the inspector: https://prnt.sc/oh8RN_8fhz-Y - only some sprites from this spritesheet are glitched, others are fine

placing a screenshot of sprite setting in inspector would help.

I added the screenshot of sprite settings in inspector.

you can upload image directly into your question :)

If anyone has the same problem and is wondering how I fixed it, in the sprite in the android section, try changing the "format" - it fixed it for me
